# Hiding my Azure VM from Public

Tags: asp.net, azure, acl

I have an active on production azure cloud service with couple of web roles running an ASP .NET MVC application, each role has few vms.

I recently added a Linux machine running a redis server to boost performance, and I want to hide this server(s) from the world, currently the VM has a public IP that can be used to connect directly to it.

I saw ACL configuration, but it requires me to allow IP ranges (CIDR), but I don't know how to figure out the ranges of my web roles

Anyone has an idea of how to totally remove the public IP or how to figure out the IP ranges of my web roles that would be great.

Comment: Seems like more of a serverfault question.

Comment: @BenV ya I was kinda hesitant to post it here, it'll be closed automatically when more people vote to close it